# classes vs styles for CSS className in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, class, material-ui

In the below code, why does a call to the `classes` object work? It seems like the call should be to the `styles` object defined as a `const` up top.

For example, [in this demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/qxv466wlq):

```
className={classes.button}
```

works as written. But it seems like it should be

```
className={styles.button}
```

Is there any actual `classes` object defined anywhere? If so, where is it defined? The markup implies a `this.props.classes` object. But there are no `props` passed to `<Demo />` when called in index.js.

What's going on here?

https://codesandbox.io/s/qxv466wlq

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const styles = theme => ({
  button: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
  },
  input: {
    display: 'none',
  },
});

function OutlinedButtons(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="outlined" className={classes.button}>
        Default
      </Button>
      <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" className={classes.button}>
        Primary
      </Button>
      <Button variant="outlined" color="secondary" className={classes.button}>
        Secondary
      </Button>
      <Button variant="outlined" disabled className={classes.button}>
        Disabled
      </Button>
      <Button variant="outlined" href="#outlined-buttons" className={classes.button}>
        Link
      </Button>
      <input
        accept="image/*"
        className={classes.input}
        id="outlined-button-file"
        multiple
        type="file"
      />
      <label htmlFor="outlined-button-file">
        <Button variant="outlined" component="span" className={classes.button}>
          Upload
        </Button>
      </label>
    </div>
  );
}

OutlinedButtons.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(OutlinedButtons);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at this line:

```
export default withStyles(styles)(OutlinedButtons);
```

the answer to your question is provided I believe. Material UI has a function [`withStyles`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/styles/withStyles.js) that takes a styles object, and then returns another function that takes a component to return a new component. This is a Higher Order Component, and can be read about on the [React docs.](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)

If you look at the linked code of `withStyles`, you can see the following line where it renders the passed in component:

```
return <Component {...more} classes={this.getClasses()} ref={innerRef} />;
```

And is providing the `classes` prop, making it available to any component exported with `withStyles`.